# What does the last digit in the ActiveMQ message ID represent?

Tags: activemq-classic

I have a system that seems to be working fine, but when a certain process writes a message, I get 10 messages appear in the queue.  They are all almost duplicates, but the last section of the message id is incremented.

Example:

```
c6743810-65e6-4bcd-b575-08174f9cae73:1:1:1
c6743810-65e6-4bcd-b575-08174f9cae73:1:1:2
c6743810-65e6-4bcd-b575-08174f9cae73:1:1:3
c6743810-65e6-4bcd-b575-08174f9cae73:1:1:4
.
.
.
```

What does this mean?  From what I can tell, the process is only writing one message.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found it...  The process WAS writing multiple messages, but using the same producer and transaction.  ActiveMQ seems to use this as a session ID or something of that sort.  Feel free to expand on this topic if you deem it necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The message id is generated to be globally unique - and consists of a combination of a your host, a unique MessageProducer Id and an incrementing sequence for each message